# How can I apply C# generics properly in this case, dealing with Entity framework and MVC action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to somehow use generics in this case or perhaps there's an entity framework
method that's more appropriate i.e `.set<Type EntityType>`. I am wishing to perform the same LinQ operation but on different entity DBsets, so say instead of repository.PCBuilds I wish to perform the operation on repository.Home etc, the name of the entity to perform the LinQ operation on would be decided by the value of the parent parameter. I would also need to return the specific view pertaining to the category value.

I could use a case switch, but just wondering if I could adopt a more generic and
flexible code. Or should I just create individual action methods for returning
the entity types and create the appropriate routing entries.

```
public PartialViewResult StoreContent(string Parent = "PCBuild" ,string category = "Desktop", int page = 1)
    {


        int pagesize = 3;

        PagingStore IndexModel = new PagingStore()
        {
            PCBuilds = repository.PCBuilds.Where(x => x.ExternalCat.CatName == category).OrderBy(x => x.BDetails.Where(c => c.IsSelected == true).Select(c => c.Product.ListPrice).Sum()).Skip((page - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList(),
            category = category,
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = pagesize,
                TotalItems = repository.PCBuilds.Where(x => x.ExternalCat.CatName == category).Count(),
            }

        };


        return PartialView(IndexModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If PCBUild and Home both have ExternalCat and BDetails and Product, then you can do this

```
public interface IProductDescription {
    Category ExternalCat { get; }
    IQueryable<Option> BDetails { get; }
}

public partial class PCBuild : IProductDescription {
}

public partial class Home : IProductDescription {
}
```

and change the method definition to:

```
IQueryable<IProductDescription> GetProductDescriptions(string setName) {
        switch(setName) {
            case "PCBuild": 
                return this.PCBuilds;
            case "Home":
                return this.Homes;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And just use it like this:
...

```
 PCBuilds = repository.GetProductDescriptions(setName)
                      .Where(x => x.ExternalCat.CatName == category)
                      .OrderBy(
                          x => x.BDetails
                                .Where(c => c.IsSelected == true)
                                .Select(c => c.Product.ListPrice)
                                .Sum())
                      .Skip((page - 1) * pagesize)
                      .Take(pagesize)
                      .ToList()
```